# How to add all childs and their values to a listview (firebase database)

Tags: java, android

I am writing this post as I am stuck,I am new to Firebase and I don't know where to go from here.

I've tried multiple solutions from stackoverflow but nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView listView;
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
List<String> itemList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listScore);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores/" + mAuth.getUid() + "/game1");

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            itemList.clear();

                Score score = dataSnapshot.getValue(Score.class);
                String gameInformation = "Date: " + score.getDate() + ", Time: " + score.getTime() + ". \nYou've chosen " + score.getCat1() + " as your range, " + score.getCat2() + " as sign of your equations and the time was " + score.getCat3() + ".\nYour score was " + score.getScore();
                itemList.add(gameInformation);

                Log.d("Test", score.getDate());                      

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HistoryActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
 }
```

And my database looks like this:

[My db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaeYv.png)
And all this is working but I have no idea how to show all the games details not only the first one, so I would be grateful for some guidance.

Edit1:
After applying suggestions of for loop I am getting following error:

[Fatal Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1WuV.png)

I think that my database reference is wrong but I've tried several methods and it is still not working...

This is my Score class:

```
public class Score {

private String cat1;
private String cat2;
private String cat3;
private String date;
private String time;
private String score;
private Long gameCount;

public Score() { }

public Score(String cat1, String cat2, String cat3, String date, String time, String score, Long gameCount) {

    this.cat1 = cat1;
    this.cat2 = cat2;
    this.cat3 = cat3;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.score = score;
    this.gameCount = gameCount;
}

public String getCat1() {
    return cat1;
}

public void setCat1(String cat1) {
    this.cat1 = cat1;
}

public String getCat2() {
    return cat2;
}

public void setCat2(String cat2) {
    this.cat2 = cat2;
}

public String getCat3() {
    return cat3;
}

public void setCat3(String cat3) {
    this.cat3 = cat3;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public Long getGameCount() {
    return gameCount;
}

public void setGameCount(Long gameCount) {
    this.gameCount = gameCount;
}
```

Edit2: 
After applying new database reference I'm getting null values and in the console I'm getting following error:

[No setter message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8CyC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Fetch all the children from snapshot

2.) Add all of them in a list

3.) use the list to populate listview using adapter.

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            itemList.clear();
            // 1
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Score score = ds.getValue(Score.class);
            // 2
                    itemList.add("Date: " + score.getDate() + ", Time: " + score.getTime() + ". \nYou've chosen " + score.getCat1() + " as your range, " + score.getCat2() + " as sign of your equations and the time was " + score.getCat3() + ".\nYour score was " + score.getScore());
                }
            // 3
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HistoryActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Although i strongly recommend to use customize adapter instead of array adapter

Update: To fetch all childs, the path of the datasnapshot reference should point to root instead of a specific child so use

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
```

Comment: Hello, your answer is definitely correct but I think that my database reference is wrong as I am getting fatal exception
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.google.firebase.MathIsEasyApp.com.Score
Full error in my edited post.

Comment: Yup , because of this path `"scores/" + mAuth.getUid() + "/game1"`, letme update the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and sorry that I am still bothering you, but now I am getting null values and also in the console I'am getting "No setter/field found" info. If it is not too much to ask please see my db structure and Score class as this is where the error is now I think...

Comment: @DavidCzuchnowski try `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores/" + mAuth.getUid());`

Comment: if there's an issue(setter/getter ) then it's due to `this.gameCount = gameCount;` because the object doesn't have any property named `gamecount` so better approach would be to move game1, game2 etc as oart of the object not parent

Comment: ok I got it, I had to move game1, game2 etc as you said and push() data to get uniqe key as a parent.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DavidCzuchnowski i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

you have to change you `onDataChange()` a little bit

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   if(dataSnapshot.exists())
   itemList.clear();
            {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Score score = postSnapShot.getValue(Score.class);
            String gameInformation = "Date: " + score.getDate() + ", Time: " + score.getTime() + ". \nYou've chosen " + score.getCat1() + " as your range, " + score.getCat2() + " as sign of your equations and the time was " + score.getCat3() + ".\nYour score was " + score.getScore();
            itemList.add(gameInformation);

            Log.d("Test", score.getDate());  
                }
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HistoryActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```